# How to sort a table made of orders by meeting date

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, meta

I'm trying to sort a list of invoices by "meeting_date" which is a meta in the database.

Heres, the code I have:

```php
<?php if ( ! empty( $invoices ) ) {
                foreach ( $invoices as $invoice ) { ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                              <span class="hs-table-facture-img"></span>
                            <a target="hs_factures_iframe" id="hs-go-to-frame" class="hs-table-facture-link" href="<?php echo $invoice['invoicing_link']; ?>">Facture # <?php echo $invoice['invoicing_number']; ?></a>
                        </td>

                        <?php if ( $show_date ) { ?>

                            <td class="hs-custom-factures-td-bold">
                                <?php
                                  $title_arr = explode(" ", $invoice['title']);

                                  // get meating date
                                $get_all_cf = get_post_meta( (int)$invoice['id'], 'wpc_inv_invoice_cf', true );
                                $meeting_date = $get_all_cf['wpc_inv_cf_meeting_date'];
                                $meeting_date = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($meeting_date));


                                ?>

                                <?php echo $meeting_date . $title_arr[0]; ?>
                            </td>
```

Right now, the invoices are presented by oldest first. My clients have to scroll alot to be able to view the invoice they need.

How can I use this to ORDER this table by meeting date?

Thanks in advance for your help.